# How to get variable from javascript to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I get such javascript:

```
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      var name = response.name;
          first_name = response.first_name;
      alert("Name: "+ name + "\nFirst name: "+ first_name);}
```

How I could get value of `name` and `first_name` to rails controller?
I use Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the value of the javascript array in a request parameter, either via ajax or by setting the value of a form input.  I'm going to use jQuery in my examples:

Option 1 (ajax):

```
$.post('/users/some_action', {"name" : name, "first_name", first_name})
```

Option 2 (setting a form):

```
$('#name').val(name)
$('#first_name').val(first_name)
```

In your controller:

```
name = params[:name]
first_name = params[:first_name]
```